# Trouble Scanning QR Code Samsung S10 that uses Google Firebase Dynamic URL

Tags: firebase, qr-code, samsung-mobile, firebase-dynamic-links

Google Firebase Dynamic URLs are complex and the one I am using pass through a lot of information such as link to app in appstore plus link to googleplay plus URL etc.

If the link is put in a button it works perfectly and I had an idea to use the long complex URL in a QR Code so that if it appears on a desktop site a user can scan the code and it will launch the appropriate app etc.

All was working well until someone mentioned it didn't work when they scanned the QR Code on their Samsung Galaxy S10 using the built-in scanner in the camera. Upon further testing it works ok with a 3rd party QR Scanner but the built-in one breaks at the :

Here is the format of the URL

https://appname.page.link?link=https://domainname.com/slug&apn=com.appname.arap etc (no point putting the full structure yet)

But the QR Scanner breaks at the second : so only sees and links to

https://appname.page.link?link=https and so gives an error message of Invalid Dynamic Link

In generating the QR the Full URL is encoded and so the : is replaced by %3A but still breaks

So I'm thinking Samsung reader thinks this is an invalid URL or a security risk but it means I can't take the Samsung User to our App and load the correct information.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this? I've been working on it all day and the only thing that worked was taking them to another page, building the full dynamic link and redirecting to it but that has caused issues with apples users and so not a solution.

The only solution would be one where I can substitute the : to something else that Samsung will like.

Anyone else run into a similar issue? It's very specific I know but it's fundamental to making the user journey as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same issue on the samsungs.
solution was not obvious but replace the : in the domain after https with %3A

https://appname.page.link?link=https://domainname.com/slug&apn=com.appname.arap
to
https://appname.page.link?link=https%3A//domainname.com/slug&apn=com.appname.arap

This worked fine with the QR generated for our purposes.